# Generate .abb file from apk or using cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apk, android-app-bundle, bundletool

As playstore requires the application in the .aab format, I want to build the same from my ionic v2 project or convert apk to .abb
The following commands did not work for me. I shall provide the details of cordova and ionic, help me with the same

1. **ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle**
2. **./gradlew bundleRelease**

Comment: Which error you got in your command line?

Comment: I did not get any error but the .abb file was not created neither was the folder bundle.

Comment: I am not familiar with ionic V2, but do you have an android map? You can open this with android studio and generate the .abb file there.

Comment: Can you share the logs you get after running the first command? It usually works with just the first command

Comment: @Fearcoder I have Android Studio Installed. But, the thing is I have done many fixes & work around to generate the build (apk). If I choose to build in Android Studio then I have to go through these stuff again I guess. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @RajeshKumar last logs line : BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 42s
43 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        H:/workspace/RetailMapp/profitguru_dev/profitGuruMAPP/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/release/android-release-unsigned.apk

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova build android --release
cd c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\platforms\android
gradlew bundle
```

Result will be here

```
c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\debug\
```

Than sign aab:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\keystore.keystore c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab alias
```

Result will be here

```
c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\bundle\release\
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did do this but did not work so I used Android Studio to do the same